# Converting double to string

Tags: java, android

I am not sure it is me or what but I am having a problem converting a double to string.

here is my code:

```
double total = 44;
String total2 = Double.toString(total);
```

Am i doing something wrong or am i missing a step here.

I get error `NumberFormatException` when trying to convert this.

```
totalCost.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    try {
      double priceG = Double.parseDouble(priceGal.getText().toString());
      double valG = Double.parseDouble(volGal.toString());
      double total = priceG * valG;
      String tot = new Double(total).toString();
      totalCost.setText(tot);
    } catch(Exception e) {
      Log.e("text", e.toString());
    }

    return false;
  }         
});
```

I am trying to do this in an onTouchListener. Ill post more code, basically when the user touches the edittext box i want the information to calculate a fill the edittext box.

Comment: Seems fine to me, what problem have you encountered?

Comment: is that the real code your are executing? those lines work perfect.

Comment: Double.toString(double) can't even throw NumberFormatException - are you sure the exception isn't being thrown from somewhere else?

Comment: There must be something else, this should work just fine. http://ideone.com/btGrv

Comment: I am not familiar with android sdk, do you think it needs to be `44.00`? The reason why I say that he is getting a `NumberFormatException` which could only mean that it thinks it's not a double.

Comment: doesn't look like any problem here, are you sure problem is at  `Double.toString()` ?

Comment: @CoolBeans  - google says, no. It can't throw that. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Double.html

Comment: Show stacktrace and whole code

Answer (score 495, accepted):

```
double total = 44;
String total2 = String.valueOf(total);
```

This will convert double to String

Comment: have the following in mind if total = 1234567890123456 then the String becomes "1.234567890123456E15" which is very often not what you want

Comment: any solution for above one?

Comment: @PrashanthDebbadwar Yes: `NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getInstance(); fmt.setGroupingUsed(false); fmt.setMaximumIntegerDigits(999); fmt.setMaximumFractionDigits(999);` then use `total2 = fmt.format(total)`

Comment: This internally calls `Double.toString()`. Not sure how it answers the question.

Comment: `String.format ("%.0f", bigDouble)`

Answer (score 35):

Using Double.toString(), if the number is too small or too large, you will get a scientific notation like this: 3.4875546345347673E-6. There are several ways to have more control of output string format.

```
double num = 0.000074635638;
// use Double.toString()
System.out.println(Double.toString(num));
// result: 7.4635638E-5

// use String.format
System.out.println(String.format ("%f", num));
// result: 0.000075
System.out.println(String.format ("%.9f", num));
// result: 0.000074636

// use DecimalFormat
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.000000");
String numberAsString = decimalFormat.format(num);
System.out.println(numberAsString);
// result: 0.000075
```

Use String.format() will be the best convenient way.

Answer (score 14):

This code compiles and works for me.  It converts a double to a string using the calls you tried.

```
public class TestDouble {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double total = 44;
        String total2 = Double.toString(total);

        System.out.println("Double is " + total2);
    }
}
```

I am puzzled by your seeing the NumberFormatException. Look at the stack trace. I'm guessing you have other code that you are not showing in your example that is causing that exception to be thrown.

Comment: I am puzzled by your seeing the NumberFormatException.  Look at the stack trace.  I'm guessing you have other code that you are not showing in your example that is causing that exception to be thrown.

Comment: So does the OP's code. There isn't a problem here to be solved.

Comment: possible, I am trying to do this in an onTouchListener. Ill post more code, basically when the user touches the edittext box i want the information to calculate a fill the edittext box.

Answer (score 6):

The exception probably comes from the parseDouble() calls. Check that the values given to that function really reflect a double.

Answer (score 3):

```
double priceG = Double.parseDouble(priceGal.getText().toString());

double valG = Double.parseDouble(volGal.toString());

double priceG = Double.parseDouble(priceGal.getText().toString());

double valG = Double.parseDouble(volGal.toString());

double priceG = Double.parseDouble(priceGal.getText().toString());

double valG = Double.parseDouble(volGal.toString());
```

it works. got to be repetitive.

Answer (score 2):

```
double total = 44;
String total2 = new Double(total).toString();
```

Comment: `Double.toString()` calls `String.valueOf(double)` which calls `Double.toString(double)`. Crazy, eh?

Comment: So does the OP's code. There isn't a problem here to be solved.

Comment: @Muhammed - Possible?? *It's what it does*

Comment: @Muhammed - no, it's not efficient. See glowcoder's comment. You're creating a new `Double` object then calling its `toString()` method which calls `String.valueOf(double)` which *finally* does what the OP did in the first place.

Comment: @Muhammed well, you're creating an object just to get its String value. If this were in a loop of some kind, you could experience a lot of additional (unnecessary) overhead. I'm not a big fan of premature optimization, but I am a fan of avoiding obvious deficiencies.

Comment: Apart from the mentioned issues, this will convert to a power of ten representation for big decimals.

Answer (score 2):

## Kotlin

You can use `.toString` directly on any data type in kotlin, like

```
val d : Double = 100.00
val string : String = d.toString()
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a very old post, but this may be the easiest way to convert it:

```
double total = 44;
String total2 = "" + total;
```

Comment: I agree my post is old now... However, using double quotes is very common way to convert values to strings. Not sure in Java these days, but in JavaScript, I often do `var total = 44; var strTotal = total + ""` to make it a string. Or `.toString()` if I really need to call it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
double priceG = Double.parseDouble(priceGal.getText().toString());
double valG = Double.parseDouble(volGal.toString());
```

One of those is throwing the exception. You need to add some logging/printing to see what's in `volGal` and `priceGal` - it's not what you think.

Comment: I changed the total to a hard number like 44 and it still gave me an error.

Comment: what "total"? Your original code snippit couldn't throw that exception. The two calls I show above can. One of your `String`s isn't a valid representation of a `double` which is why you're getting that exception.

Comment: To be clear; `Double.toString(total);` *can not throw an exception. Ever.*. You changed that to `new Double(total).toString();` which also can't and if you see the answer here that's been voted down it is not something you ever want to do.

Comment: ok ill get that changed. I moved that litle bit of code out of the ontouchlistener and it worked fine. but when it is in the ontouchlistener it throws the error.

I am trying to do this in an onTouchListener. Ill post more code, basically when the user touches the edittext box i want the information to calculate a fill the edittext box.

Answer (score 1):

`double.toString()` should work. Not the variable type `Double`, but the variable itself `double`.

Comment: you should consider that sometimes it will return number with E scientific notation like -2.23561E5

Answer (score 1):

## Complete Info

You can use String.valueOf() for float, double, int, boolean etc.

```
double d = 0;
float f = 0;
int i = 0;
short i1 = 0;
char c = 0;
boolean bool = false;
char[] chars = {};
Object obj = new Object();


String.valueOf(d);
String.valueOf(i);
String.valueOf(i1);
String.valueOf(f);
String.valueOf(c);
String.valueOf(chars);
String.valueOf(bool);
String.valueOf(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways to convert **double to String**.

1. Double.toString(d)
2. String.valueOf(d)
3. ""+d

   public class DoubleToString {

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       double d = 122;
       System.out.println(Double.toString(d));
       System.out.println(String.valueOf(d));
       System.out.println(""+d);

   }
   ```

   }

**String to double**

1. Double.parseDouble(str);

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following:

```
doublevalue+"";
```

This will work for any data type.

**Example:**

```
Double dd=10.09;
String ss=dd+"";
```

Comment: Very bad habit to stringify by adding to an empty String. Use dedicated JDK func instead

Comment: @Michael.P why is it bad?

Comment: I've been doing this for like all my time as a java programmer lol.

Comment: Desugars to String ss=new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(dd)).append("");

Comment: Unless there is some compile-time optimization at play, it would call an additional constructor and append method.

Comment: It first creates a new String with `new String(new char[] {})`, then uses `Double.toString()` to convert the double into a string, and then does `String.concat()` to add the two together. Two extra operations. It's not good to use this method. Simple, but effective for causing lag.

Comment: Always use String.valueOf(dd) instead. This will also work for any data type.

Answer (score 0):

How about when you do the

```
totalCost.setText(tot);
```

You just do

```
totalCost.setText( "" + total );
```

Where the "" + < variable > will convert it to string automaticly

Answer (score 0):

When you would like to format the decimal and convert it to a `String` `DecimalFormat` helps much.

**Example:**

```
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#.####");
format.format(yourDoubleObject);
```

[image]

These are various symbols that are supported as part of pattern in [DecimalFomat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).

Answer (score -1):

Use `StringBuilder` class, like so:

```
StringBuilder meme = new StringBuilder(" ");

// Convert and append your double variable
meme.append(String.valueOf(doubleVariable));

// Convert string builder to string
jTextField9.setText(meme.toString());
```

You will get you desired output.

Answer (score -1):

This is a very old post, but java double to string conversion can be done in many ways, I will go through them one by one with example code snippets.

**1. Using + operator**

This is the easiest way to convert double to string in java.

```
double total = 44;
String total2 = total + "";
```

**2. Double.toString()**

We can use Double class `toString` method to get the string representation of double in decimal points. Below code snippet shows you how to use it to convert double to [string in java.](https://www.journaldev.com/16928/java-string)

```
double total = 44;
String total2 = Double.toString(total);
```

**3. String.valueOf()**

```
double total = 44;
String total2 = String.valueOf(total);
```

**4. new Double(double l)**

Double constructor with double argument has been deprecated in [Java 9](https://www.journaldev.com/13121/java-9-features-with-examples), but you should know it.

```
double total = 44;
//deprecated from Java 9, use valueOf for better performance
String total2 = new Double(total).toString();
```

**5. String.format()**

We can use [Java String format](https://www.journaldev.com/17850/java-string-format) method to convert double to String in our programs.

```
double total = 44;
String total2 = String.format("%f", total);
```

**6. DecimalFormat**

We can use `DecimalFormat` class to convert double to String. We can also get string representation with specified decimal places and rounding of half-up.

```
double total = 44;
String total2 = DecimalFormat.getNumberInstance().format(total);

//if you don't want formatting
total2 = new DecimalFormat("#.0#").format(total); // rounded to 2 decimal places

total2 = new DecimalFormat("#.0#").format(44); // rounded to 2 decimal places
```

**7. StringBuilder, StringBuffer**

We can use [StringBuilder](https://www.journaldev.com/16833/java-stringbuilder) and [StringBuffer](https://www.journaldev.com/16827/stringbuffer-in-java) append function to convert double to string.

```
double total = 44;
String total2 = new StringBuilder().append(total).toString();
```

Comment: Identical content [at Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/java-convert-double-to-string) (likely plagiarised from the same place).