# Properly converting a double variable to string

Tags: java, string, double

I am trying to take a Double variable  called 'startCheckNumber' which should have a value of '40305555' and convert to String.  In doing a debug of my code the startCheckNumber shows a value of 4.030555E7.  If I do the following command to convert to String it shows it like that instead of '4030555'

```
   String displayCheckNumber = String.valueOf(startCheckNumber)   ;
```

Is there a better way to convert a double variable to String in this case than using ValueOf?  I tried 'Double.toString(number)' format and that didn't work right

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to do it in Javascript or Java?

Comment: You could try `NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(startCheckNumber)` or `String.format("%f", startCheckNumber );`.

Comment: Is a duplicate of [*How to print double value without scientific notation using Java?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098046/how-to-print-double-value-without-scientific-notation-using-java). Is not a duplicate of [*Converting double to string*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766318/converting-double-to-string) (the answers there just say to do what's above).

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I should have looked harder.  I found and this seemed to work

```
   DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#");
   String displayCheckNumber = decimalFormat.format(startCheckNumber);
```

Comment: I was absolutely sure the code in your question wouldn't produce the string you showed () until [I tried it](http://ideone.com/ruiykp). Talk about surprising. I mean, yes, 4.030555E7 == 40305555, they're just in different notations, but...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder 4.030555E7 != 40305555  Notice the different number of 5's

Comment: @FredK: That's just a typo in the question (what I get for copy and paste from there rather than the linked output). The actual output has all of the 5s in the scientific notation.