# Adding +1 to the end of a String

Tags: java

**Good Morning,**

I have a String = "1481807989.1524"

I need to add + 1 to this string

**Example 1:**

String = "1481807989.1524"

New String = "1481807989.1525"

**Example 2:**

String = "1481807989.1999"

New String = "1481807989.2000"

I tried to do it this way but it did not answer:

```
String str;

Str = str.charAt (str.length () - 1);
```

Comment: You have to change the number to float, do the math you want, and then turn back into String.

Comment: Is it one decimal number and do you want to add 0.001; or are there two numbers, separated by '.'?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769669/convert-string-to-double-in-java, then add, then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766318/converting-double-to-string

Comment: What you gotta do, I know.

But how to do in java (Code) I am in difficulties could help me?

Comment: @RafaelCalino look at what Tom just linked. People are not here to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parse the value as a whole and then add the value you desire.

```
new BigDecimal(/* your string */).add(BigDecimal.ONE)
```

Or if I read your code correctly, you always want to add `new BigDecimal("0.001")`.

EDIT: if you really want to just change the last digit, use something like the following:

```
public BigDecimal incrementLastDigit(String value) {
    BigDecimal decimal = new BigDecimal(value);
    return new BigDecimal(decimal.unscaledValue().add(BigInteger.ONE), decimal.scale());
}
```

Samples:

```
incrementLastDigit("1234.1234"); // gets you 1234.1235
incrementLastDigit("1234.1"); // gets you 1234.2
incrementLastDigit("9999999999999999999999999999999999.99999999999999999999999999999"); 
// gets you 10000000000000000000000000000000000.00000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: the string could be `123`, `123.1` , '123.123`, '8999999999999999999999999999.999999999999999999999999`. anyway, hard coded `0.001` looks not nice.

Comment: Agreed. This should rather lead in the right direction. The pattern I saw, was that `0.0001` was added ;-) And regarding the input strings. Don't forget, that "nonsense" is a valid input string too ;-) Sanity checks were not asked ;-)

Comment: I did the function but look at the result:

VAR: 1481811454.1579
VAR NEW: 1481811455.1579


He has to change in 1579.