# JTextArea.setText not visible

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to use `JTextArea.setText` in java to put me something up to the window. I wanted to get my screensize into `textarea`, however, one of two `.setText()` is not showing anything to the screen.

My code:

```
public class SimpleFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Demo");
        Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        double hi = d.getHeight();
        double wi = d.getWidth();
        JTextArea area = new JTextArea(10, 10);
        area.setEditable(false);
        area.setText("height: " + hi);
        area.setText("width: " + wi);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.add(area); 
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
width: 1920.0
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to [append](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append(java.lang.String)) your text with `area.append("...");` since `area.setText("...");` overrides the content.

> [`public void append(String str)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append(java.lang.String)):
>   Appends the given text to the end of the document.
>
> [`public void setText(String t)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setText(java.lang.String)):
>   Sets the text of this TextComponent to the specified text.

Comment: Thank you for fast answer. It works:). By the way, I was wondering how do I add (append) non-string type of variables. Like I want to do append(height) without a text. Is that possible?

Comment: I guess `area.append("" + height);` should do the trick. Otherwise you could convert `height` to String with `Double.toString(height);` or something like this. There should be plenty of [examples here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766318/converting-double-to-string). Edit: @sumu00 My bad, you are right ;) Should be: `String.valueOf(height);`

Comment: Yeah "" should do it. Double.ToString gives error, not possible to use toString on primitive type