# How do I use a toString() method to replace a display method?

Tags: java

I'm asked to modify the class Staff by replacing the `displaySalary()` method with the `toString()` method that returns all required information to be displayed and print S.O.P in the `main` method but I don't even know where to start because as I have declared, `salary` is a `double`, how are we going to use a `String`? I'm really lost with this. It will be a gratitude if I'm advised where to start.

This is the given code:

```
class Staff {

    private String name, staffID;
    private double salary;
    private double commission;
    private int workingHours;
    private double Sales;
    public void setStaffInfo(String nm, String id, int wHour, double sale) 
    {
        name=nm;
        staffID=id;
        workingHours=wHour;
        Sales=sale;
    }

    public void calculateSalary(){
        salary = (workingHours*8);
    }

    public double displaySalary(){
        return salary;
    }

    public String displayName(){
        return name;
    }

    public String displayStaffID(){
        return staffID;
    }

    public double displayworkingHours(){
        return workingHours;
    }

    public double displaySales(){
        return Sales;

    }

    public void calculateCommission(){

        if(Sales >= 150 && Sales <= 300)
            commission= (0.05*Sales);


        else if(Sales >=301 && Sales <= 500)
            commission= (0.1*Sales);


        else if (Sales > 500)
            commission=(0.15*Sales);

        else
            commission= 0;

    }

    public double displayCommission(){
        return commission;
    }

}
```

This is the code for the main method:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class TestStaff {
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String arg[]){

        Staff staff1= new Staff();


        System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
        String nm=scan.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter your Staff ID: ");
        String id=scan.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter your working hours: ");
        int wHour=scan.nextInt(); 

        System.out.print("Enter your total sales: ");
        double sale=scan.nextDouble();

        staff1.setStaffInfo(nm, id, wHour, sale);
        staff1.calculateCommission();
        staff1.calculateSalary();
        System.out.println("\nStaff Name: " + staff1.displayName());
        System.out.println("Staff ID: " + staff1.displayStaffID());
        System.out.println("Hours worked: " + staff1.displayworkingHours());
        System.out.println("Total sales: RM" +staff1.displaySales());

        double com= staff1.displayCommission();
        double sala= staff1.displaySalary();
        double total= sala+com;

        System.out.println("Salary: RM" + total);

    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `Double.toString(salary)`.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766318/converting-double-to-string) may help you. Also, you haven't specified *how* the `toString` method should display the information. Like, all the values one after the other separated by commas?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca oh no no, the values should start at every next line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When put object to `System.out.println`, the `toString` method of that object is called.

If you don't provide an overridden version then it will print something likes `Staff@123f23` which is the object pointer.

So all you have to do is overload the `toString` method inside class `Staff` with your display logic. For example:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    double com= staff1.displayCommission();
    double sala= staff1.displaySalary();
    double total= sala+com;

    return "Staff Name: " + staff1.displayName())
    + "\nStaff ID: " + staff1.displayStaffID())
    + "\nHours worked: " + staff1.displayworkingHours())
    + "\nTotal sales: RM" +staff1.displaySales())
    + "\nSalary: RM" + total );
}
```

Comment: i encountered problem at the main method where it states String cannot be converted to double

Comment: double com= staff1.displayCommission();
   String sala= staff1.toString();
   double total= sala+com;
   
   System.out.println("Salary: RM" + total);
   
   }
 }

Comment: This will cause error `String sala= staff1.toString(); double total= sala+com;` because you can't plus a string with a double.

Comment: that means do i have to make some amendment at the double total= sala+com;? what should I do then?

Comment: I think you misunderstood the requirement. Normally use toString() is enough. See my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

Just override the to String method like this

```
public String toString(){
      //write which field you need to show
      return Double.toString(d);
      // Here you append other column as per your need. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
System.out.println("Hours worked: " + staff1.displayworkingHours());
```

with

```
System.out.println("Hours worked: " + Double.toString(staff1.displayworkingHours()));
```

and this

```
System.out.println("Total sales: RM" +staff1.displaySales());
```

with

```
System.out.println("Total sales: RM" + Double.toString(staff1.displaySales()));
```

Logic is, first covert your double column to string by using toString(yourDoubleColumn) and, concatenate string with a string

Ask me if you are still facing issues