# Convert Toast.makeText to textView setText

Tags: android, google-maps, location, settext, android-fusedlocation

I create apps to get user locations in coordinate like latitude and longitude, so I use play-service-location, my program code is below:

`import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private Location mLastLocation;
    private Button btLocation;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setupGoogleAPI();

        // initialize button
        btLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_getLocation);
        btLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mLastLocation != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this," Get Location \n " +
                            "Latitude : "+ mLastLocation.getLatitude()+
                            "\nLongitude : "+mLastLocation.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void setupGoogleAPI(){
        // initialize Google API Client
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
                .Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // connect ke Google API Client ketika start
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // disconnect ke Google API Client ketika activity stopped
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        // get last location ketika berhasil connect 
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            Toast.makeText(this," Connected to Google Location API", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
}`

as seen above, I use toast to display the coordinates, the problem is when I experiment with adding setText to display coordinates, there is an error

> error: no suitable method found for setText(double) method
>   TextView.setText(CharSequence) is not applicable (argument mismatch;
>   double cannot be converted to CharSequence) method
>   TextView.setText(int) is not applicable (argument mismatch; possible
>   lossy conversion from double to int

I have tried several days and the result is always error, how I display the coordinates in setText, so the coordinates can be seen in textView?

Comment: Where TextView is located in your code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your Toast is that it uses doubles instead of strings therefore you cannot set

> " Get Location \n " +
>                               "Latitude : "+ mLastLocation.getLatitude()+
>                               "\nLongitude : "+mLastLocation.getLongitude()

as your textview. Try converting `mLastLocation.getLatitude()`and `mLastLocation.getLongitude()` to strings before setting it as a textView. Check this answer out([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9963574/9554176))

Answer (score 0):

This issue is just a simply matter of casting your `double` values to the expected type--`String` will do nicely. Java provides several methods for this:

```
double lat = mLastLocation.getLatitude();

String latString1 = String.valueOf(lat);
String latString2 = Double.toString(lat);
```

or even simply quick and dirty (often frown upon!):

```
String latString3 = "" + lat;
```

Now simply use `setText()` like this:

```
myTextView.setText(latStringX);
```

"X" for which ever variation you choose.

**General Comment on Conversion:**
If the value you wish to convert is (for some reason) `null`, then 
`String.valueOf()` will return `null`, but `Double.toString()` will throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: remain the same, it gets     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: @laura :: According to your statement your were getting the error `setText(double) method TextView.setText(CharSequence) is not applicable (argument mismatch; double cannot be converted to CharSequence)`, but now you say you get `NullPointerException`. Please read my answer carefully! It states that if you try to convert `null` with `Double.toString()` you get a `NullPointerException`. When you try to convert `null` with `String.valueOf()` you get `null` return.

Comment: @laura :: please edit your original post and show exactly how your are using `setText()`, on which object, how and where you declare that object.